# Use generic argument in method body <T>

Tags: json, swift, generics

I'm trying to create a generic method like the following:

```
private func map<T>(type:T, jsonString:String) -> T
{
    do
    {
        let model = try Mapper<type>().map(JSONString: jsonString)!
        return model
    }
    catch
    {
        Log.error("Failed to convert JSON jsonString to model object: \(jsonString)")
    }
    return EmptyModel()
}
```

but it result in compile error:
Error: use of undeclared type 'type'

How can I change it to use the specified type (a class object) with the Mapper's generic value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `T` instead of `type`:

```
let model = try Mapper<T>().map(JSONString: jsonString)!
```

You might want to change method signature, so it returns an instance of `T` and not the type `T` itself:

```
private func map<T>(type: T.Type, jsonString: String) -> T
```

That being said, Swift already has its `JSONDecoder`. It might already support what you are trying to implement.

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let model = try decoder.decode(Model.self, from: data)
```

Comment: Thanks but there is a problem: Mapper is part of Swift ObjectMapper framework. If i try to compile with your solution I get error: ype 'T' does not conform to protocol 'BaseMappable'. i suppose the specified type (class) needs to be adhering from ObjectMapper's BaseMappable class. How would I have to change above code for that?

Comment: You can require protocol conformance in generics by `<T: BaseMappable>`.